# Adding feature to Jquery plugin for angular Directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need to use a jQuery plugin (iviewer), as i have read we should be creating angular directives to use jQuery plugins. 
Question: I need to add new features also to the plugin, so should i be modifying the jQuery plugin itself them using it in the directive or should I just add the new feature in the directive itself ?

Comment: Most likely need to modify plugin itself but that is a guess since question is so vague

Comment: I'm just asking in general what should be the approach . Modify plugin or just directive

Comment: Would depend on plugin access

Comment: not sure about best approach but a good approach would be to find the repo of the plugin and fork it, this will help you receive any updates by the plugin maintainer.

Comment: @NikhilBhandari not what I'm asking, I need to modify the plugin according to my needs.